# ¿Como pasar valor de un dropDownList a un textinput?

Tags: yii2

el dropdown y el textinput se encuentran dentro de una vista, necesito de obtener el valor que tiene el dropdown y que dependiendo del valor seleccionado se actualice el textinput con la informacion seleccionada en el dropdown list.

```
    echo $form->field($FRC, 'profesores')->dropDownList(
     ArrayHelper::map(ModelComunProfesores::find()
     ->all(),'PRO_INSTITUTO','PRO_NOMBRE'),
   [ 'id'=>'subcat-id',
     'prompt' => 'Selecciona un profesor',

   ]);

echo $form->field($FRC, 'name')->textInput(['id'=>'nivel']);
```

Comment: ¿qué es un dropdown?

Comment: Es una lista desplegable, solo que en yii2 se llama dropdownList

Comment: Ok, en bootstrap los hay, como un menu desplegable,  no se si son del mismo tipo https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_dropdowns.asp

Answer (score 1):

Podés chequear el valor en el evento `onchange` del dropdown y dependiendo su valor actualizar el `input`. 
El código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
echo $form->field($FRC, 'profesores')->dropDownList(
     ArrayHelper::map(ModelComunProfesores::find()->all(),'PRO_INSTITUTO','PRO_NOMBRE'),
    [ 
        'id' => 'subcat-id',
        'prompt' => 'Selecciona un profesor',
        'onchange' => '
                if (this.value === "valor-del-dropdown-que-modifica-el-input") {
                    $("#nivel").val(this.value);
                }
            }
        ',
    ]);

echo $form->field($FRC, 'name')->textInput(['id'=>'nivel']);
```